# Bring last three words of a string to the beginning

Tags: php

I want to bring the last three words of a string to its beginning. For example, these two variables:

```
$vari1 = "It is a wonderful goodbye letter that ultimately had a happy ending.";
$vari2 = "The Science Museum in London is a free museum packed with interactive exhibits.";
```

Should become:

```
"A happy ending - It is a wonderful goodbye letter that ultimately had."
"With interactive exhibits - The Science Museum in London is a free museum packed."
```

Comment: no its not.... i have tried this example, but wounder how to count and then bring the last three in.

Comment: Then show us what have you tried so we can improve it.

Comment: $pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exploding, rearranging, and then imploding should work. See the example [here](http://codepad.org/rrsPeg6W)

```
$array = explode(" ", substr($input_string,0,-1));
array_push($array, "-");
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
   array_unshift($array, array_pop($array));
$output_string = ucfirst(implode(" ", $array)) . ".";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$split = explode(" ",$vari1);
$last = array_pop($split);
$last = preg_replace("/\W$/","",$last);
$sec = array_pop($split);
$first = array_pop($split);
$new = implode(" ",array(ucfirst($first),$sec,$last)) . " - " . implode(" ",$split) . ".";
```

Or similar should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to love me tender. <3

```
function switcheroo($sentence) {
    $words = explode(" ",$sentence);
    $new_start = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $new_start = array_pop($words)." ".$new_start;
    }
    return ucfirst(str_replace(".","",$new_start))." - ".implode(" ",$words).".";
}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily want to remove *all* periods.

Comment: True. Okay, I edited it to removed periods from the beginning 3 words at the end of the switch.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the exact same output that you want in only 2 lines of code

```
$array = explode(' ', $vari1);
echo ucfirst(str_replace('.', ' - ', join(' ', array_merge(array_reverse(array(array_pop($array), array_pop($array), array_pop($array))), $array)))) . '.';
```

Comment: Why not go ahead and make it one line? It's just as readable ;-)